# Large images in a User's 'AboutMe' can push info below the fold

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

User [The Encapsulator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/52443/the-encapsulator) has put a largish image in the AboutMe section of her or his profile.  The AboutMe box becomes scrollable as a result, but the rest of the page is pushed below the fold by a large blank space.

Comment: Really? That little white square with a red X is too big?

Comment: What OS/Browser?

Comment: Yeah, looks correct to me using Safari 4

Comment: XP, Firefox 3.6.3

Comment: In Chrome 4.1.249 it works sometimes but not all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm this on Win7 with both Chrome and Firefox.  It looks correct in IE8.

Comment: ***gasp*** something looks correct in IE?

Answer (score 4):

It happens on both Firefox and Chrome.

If at first it doesn't happen to you, change tabs and you'll see it.

I noticed it too on my own profile.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like crap in Chrome on OS X.